# How to select text vertically in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice

In word processors like MS Word, one can select text **vertically *and* horizontally** using the pointer. For example, on macOS one would hold down the `<OPTION>` key, and then `<CLICK>` to start a text selection bounding box. Once selected, operations like `Cut` operate across all lines and columns/horizontal space. One can `Paste` the `Cut` text across multiple lines as well. It's not necessarily an everyday feature for me, but when I need it it is tremendously useful.

Does this functionality exist in LibreOffice 7.0.6 (I am running on Ubuntu with Gnome Desktop via XOrg)?

If so, how do I access it?  (I am running on Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome Desktop via XOrg.)

Answer (score 2):

Click the menu Edit -> Selection Mode -> Block Area (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>).

[image]

You can also switch selection modes by clicking near the bottom of the window:
[image]

I found a youtube video that explains the selection modes in Libreoffice: https://youtu.be/K6TonGiDWaw?t=348

Comment: +1 Dragging while holding `<CTRL>` does not work on my system. Neither does dragging while holding `<ALT>` (this mnimizes the window and drags the window instead). Neither does holding `<SUPER>` and dragging, nor using `<SHIFT>` with any of these.

Comment: @Lexible Does toggling the selection mode work?

Comment: Absolutely! And I thank you for directing my attention to that! :D